# Will my Irish passport number change on renewal?

Tags: online-resources, passport-renewals, irish-citizens

I am about to renew my Irish passport, and want to know if the passport number that I have will change? I have the newer type of passport that can be renewed online.

Comment: I think it will change. All passport numbers that I have seen change on the new copies.